# Assign a CSS Element a Class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to make all `h3` elements be of the class `responsive-heading` through CSS. For a better idea of what I am trying to achieve please see the CSS code below:

```
h3 { .responsive-heading }

/* The class responsive-heading is implemented inside another CSS file and its contents are:
    .responsive-heading { font-size: 30px; .... etc. }
*/
```

I am aware I could use Javascript and/or JQuery for assigning each `h3` the class `.responsive-heading` but I before I start doing that I'd rather know if there is a css way?

In short: I want to apply `.responsive-heading` style to all `h3`. We hav hundreds of pages to update the H3 elements.

Comment: `<H3 class="responsive-heading"></H3>`?

Comment: Are you saying you want to give 'h3' the exact same styles as '.responsive-heading' but can't apply that class name in the HTML? If so, no, CSS doesn't do that.

Comment: @JunM thanks for the comment yes this will work fine. But we have hundreds of pages to edit. A CSS solution like above would be an easy broad sweeping change that would be preferred to going through each page and editting each h3 class

Comment: @DA yes. I want to apply `.responsive-heading` style to all `h3`

Comment: @Mack: Can you change the CSS? That's the obvious thing to do, add `h3` to the selector, e.g. change `.responsive-heading { ...}` to `h3, .responsive-heading { ...}` in the CSS.

Comment: The CSS file where `.responsive-heading` is defined is a wordpress file developed by a third party so changing that file is a last resort

Comment: Why is editing the CSS file a last resort? That's one of the main benefits of an external CSS file...to make it easier to do quick site-wide style changes. If touching that file is a no-no, you could create a new file that over-rides the default one.

Answer (score 7):

As stated, no you can't do that.

However, in your CSS, you can simply apply the same styles to H3s.

```
h3, .responsive-heading {...styles...}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use css to change the class of an element.

Answer (score 0):

If you could or would modify the external css,

you can change the selector to

```
h3, .responsive-heading {
    ...styles...
}
```

Or you can copy style rules of `.responsive-heading` to your h3 style, if you really sure ALL h3 should implement this.

Besides, I have to say hundreds of pages are not that many. If I was you, I will search h3 in my code and add the class to every one when I'm sure that one is one of whom need the class.